# Subtracting dates in unix

Tags: ksh, date, aix

Is there a way in unix to subtract a month or at least 30 days from a specific date? The date is to be inputted by the user.

Example:

2012-11-19 - 1 month = 2013-10-19

This one doesn't work:

```
date -d '2013-10-13 - 1 month' '+%F'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no portable tool to do date arithmetic. I think your best bet is to implement date arithmetic in ksh (and I know there is code on the web for that).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to convert the date to a unix time_t value (i.e. seconds since the beginning of the epoch, or '1-1-1970 00:00:00'), and then substract 30 days * 86400 seconds per day from that number.

e.g.  the following example uses `set -x` so that you can see the value of the D variable as it changes.

```
#! /bin/ksh

set -x

D=$(date -d '2013-10-13' '+%s')
D=$((D - 30 * 86400))

date -d "@$D"
```

Note that this depends on the GNU version of `date`, from GNU Coreutils.  Other versions of date may not support converting a time_t value back to a formatted date with `@`.  Unless you have installed GNU coreutils, this probably isn't available on your AIX system so `gawk` is probably your best option to convert back to a formatted date:

```
echo "$D" | gawk '{print strftime("%c", $0)}'
```

my original answer here suggested plain awk, but further testing on my debian system has revealed that neither `mawk` nor `original-awk` have the `strftime` function built-in, so you'll have to install either GNU Coreutils or GNU Awk.

If perl is installed on the system, perl can be used instead of awk:

```
echo $D | perl -nE 'say scalar gmtime $_'
```

There are several alternative methods and examples of doing this at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249827/convert-from-unixtime-at-command-line

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
date --date="$(date -d "Nov 1 2012")-1 month" +'%Y:%m:%d'
2012:10:01
```

Nov 1 2012 is used for illustration. That can be of any user input date.

Answer (score 0):

Your example uses relative items in date strings which are a GNU date extension.

For example on Fedora 19 your example works as expected:

```
$ date -d '2013-10-13 - 1 month' '+%F'
2013-09-13
```

Thus, you can make sure that your script uses GNU date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DAY30=`TZ=EST+720 date "+%Y-%m-%d"`

print $DAY30
```

720 is the offset in hours.  So, 30 days is 720 hours.

EST is my time zone.  I assume that you can use whatever time zone is appropriate.

Comment: What system allows offsets greater than `99:59:59`?