# Convert string to date in AIX and get difference between date time

Tags: scripting, date, aix

I have a log file like this:

```
2019.09.02 06:40:28 ---
2019.09.02 06:43:34 --- 
2019.09.02 06:43:41 ---
```

I need to read the file and get the difference between datetime "*2019.09.02 06:43:34*" -and- "*2019.09.02 06:40:28*" in hours minutes, and seconds.

```
while read date time message
do
    if [[ $date = $searched_date* ]] && [[ $message = *$searched_message* ]] ; then
      #how to convert $date and $time to unixtime?
    fi
done <"$LOG_FILE"
```

I am using AIX 7, and there is no such thing as `date -d`.

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97314/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93656/subtracting-dates-in-unix and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265951/date-1-month-ago-not-working-in-aix/265953#265953

Comment: You're interested in the resulting number of seconds, or rolled up into some version of years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds difference?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the loop in your script, because it presumably only finds one line at a time, which makes subtraction difficult. What would be subtracted in your example?

Comment: this loop is just an example, actually, it will be made of many ifs. I am interested in the difference of hours minutes seconds...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ksh93's `printf` understands your input format, so you could use:

```
end=$(printf '%(%s)T' "2019.09.02 06:43:34")
start=$(printf '%(%s)T' "2019.09.02 06:40:28")
printf '%d\n' "$((1567421014-1567420828))"
```

or more generally:

```
seconds=$(printf '%(%s)T' "$date $time")
```

To convert the difference in seconds to to hh:mm:ss:

```
printf '%d hours, %d minutes, and %d seconds\n' "$((diff / 3600))" "$(( (diff % 3600) / 60))"  "$((diff % 60))"
```

Comment: I don't have a great reference for the `printf` formats, but https://ast-users.research.att.narkive.com/sQqnDD7A/printf-t-question is a start.

Comment: See also [this test file in the source](https://github.com/att/ast/blob/2f2b1b8be315df029ce83c2ccc12a16fdcf73f29/src/cmd/tests/date.dat) for examples of what is supported.

Comment: result for `printf '%(%s)T' "2019.09.02 06:43:34"` is `()T` just empty, maybe it has to do something with my ksh version?

Comment: The result didn't have a newline, so does it exist at the beginning of your next prompt? The code does require ksh93, so make sure you're not invoking plain "ksh".

Comment: yes this was the problem ksh93, other code also works as expected. Tnak you.